# Nokogiri: how to find the selected option of <select> when select="selected" does not exist

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm new to Nokogiri and need to find the selected option of the code below. In the below when this was copy/pasted, Pink was the option selected but there is nothing in the HTML to indicate this.

Now previously I have used: `page.at('select[name="Color"] option:not(:first-of-type)[@selected]').text` (similar methods can be found here: [Nokogiri: how to find the selected option of <select>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466198/nokogiri-how-to-find-the-selected-option-of-select))  to find the value of the selected option, but for this particular site that I'm trying to scrape, there is no `selected = "selected"`.

In the past for scraping with jQuery, I've used `$('select').children("option:not(:first-of-type)").filter(":selected").text();` which manages to bypass this issue but adding a CSS selector in Nokogiri like `page.at(".variation-trait[aria-label='Select Color'] option:selected").text` isn't doing the trick for me either.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <select class="variation-trait" aria-label="Select Color" id="trait-0" data-bhw="VariationsTrait:color" data-bhw-path="FeaturedDeal|deal:73dcb228-e425-11e7-bf04-00259060b5da|VariationsWidget|success:variations-displayed|VariationsTrait:color">
     <option class="variation-option" value="Select Color" id="trait-0-0" data-bhc="option:select-color">
          Select Color
     </option>
     <option class="variation-option force-display" value="Black" id="trait-0-1" data-bhc="option:black" disabled="disabled"><span class="sold-out-text">(SOLD OUT)</span>
          Black
     </option>
     <option class="variation-option" value="White" id="trait-0-2" data-bhc="option:white">
          White
      </option>
      <option class="variation-option" value="Blue" id="trait-0-3" data-bhc="option:blue">
          Blue
      </option>
      <option class="variation-option" value="Gray" id="trait-0-4" data-bhc="option:gray">
          Gray
      </option>
      <option class="variation-option" value="Pink" id="trait-0-5" data-bhc="option:pink">
          Pink
      </option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no [selected] option, then it's the first one, so:

```
page.at('option[selected]') || page.at('option')
```

Comment: `page.at('option')` always returns the first <option> tag in the <select> as it should, but `page.at('option[selected]')` still doesn't give me a result.

Comment: Right, if `page.at('option[selected]')` is empty, then you want the first option. Right?

Comment: Not exactly. I want whatever the user has selected but the first of type (because the value of "Select Color" is useless data to me). I just wanted to see if there was a way to get the selected option. If it helps, it's for this page : https://www.groupon.com/deals/gg-arm-compression-sleeves-for-men-and-women-2-pack-1

Comment: The first selected option is `page.at('option[selected]')`

Comment: Though like I said, I don't want the first selected option, that still wouldn't work unless in the HTML the `selected` attribute existed, which it doesn't. I'm assuming this isn't possible with Nokogiri since the attribute doesn't exist in the HTML and that's what Nokogiri would need to successfully scrape. I was just curious if anyone knew/knows of a solution around this problem, which has become quite common for me when scraping sites.

Comment: Right, that's where the `|| page.at('option')` comes in. I'm not going to keep trying to convince you that this is the right answer, but this is the right answer.